# How to change the desktop folder from "Desktop - Local" to a different folder on mac?

Tags: macos, applescript

The files that are displayed on the desktop come from the folder

> /Users/USER/Desktop

I am wondering if there is any way to be able to change that so the files that are displayed on the desktop come from a different folder?

The aim behind this is to use Google Drive (https://www.google.com/drive/download/) and create a "Desktop" folder in my Drive account allowing me to sync and access my Desktop from anywhere without using as much storage locally with all the files at the desktop being displayed from

> /Users/USER/Google Drive/Mac Desktop

Comment: The UNIX / macOS file system is a quite fragile thing. If you know what you are doing you can widely customize it, but if you don't you are discouraged from making those changes because you can easily break the entire operating system.

Comment: This symlink seems to revert automatically after a while (Desktop)

Answer (score 15):

Move everything you have on your Desktop to the cloud:

```
mv ~/Desktop/* ~/Dropbox/MyDesktopOnTheCloud/
```

Remove your current local Desktop folder from your home directory:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop
```

Create a symlink to your Desktop folder on the cloud:

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/MyDesktopOnTheCloud ~/Desktop
```

**On MacOS Catalina**, in order to prevent the system from deleting your symlink and creating a blank Desktop folder after every system restart, change the flag of the symlink:

```
sudo chflags -h schg ~/Desktop
```

It's important to specify the *-h* option to instruct the *chflags* command not to follow the symlink. In this way, the link is unchangeable by the system, but the destination folder is not. The system can indeed save screenshots to the Desktop, for instance. If you omit the *-h* option, the symlink will be deleted after reboot and the folder in Dropbox will be marked as unchangeable instead.

Comment: I want to cancel the symlink, so I am trying to unset the schg flag on an M1 Mac. Normally this would be done in Single User Mode but there is no more such a mode on M1. I am stuck with a locked folder now.

Comment: I was able to remove the lock using:

`sudo chflags noschg /etc/hosts`

Comment: be careful, this will not copy the `.` dot files

Comment: [Will the screenshots work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834712/how-to-change-the-desktop-folder-from-desktop-local-to-a-different-folder-on#comment107805400_60380118) after `sudo chflags -h schg ~/Desktop`?

Answer (score 14):

**Backup your old default Desktop folder**

If you have files in your existing Desktop folder, don’t worry. We’re going to back up your existing folder so you can copy your old Desktop files to your new DropBox Desktop folder afterwards.

Simply open a terminal and enter the following command.

```
sudo mv desktop desktop.bak
```

**Create a symbolic link to your new DropBox Desktop folder**

The long and short is that we’re telling OSX to create a link to the Desktop folder in your DropBox, but to treat the link as if it were the default Desktop folder itself. In this way, when you save things to your Mac Desktop, they’ll appear on your Desktop as before, but actually be stored in your new DropBox folder. Here’s how to do it…

```
ln -s /Users/your-user-name/Dropbox/Desktop/ ./Desktop
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Credit goes to https://ifyouwillit.com/life/auto-sync-your-mac-desktop-folder-with-dropbox/

Comment: This approach did work, but broke some time in 2019. MacOS now regularly removes the symlink and replaces it with a new Desktop folder

Comment: I've read complaints that it broke, but it has been working fine on my machine for years now (June 2023).

Answer (score 3):

I found that MacOS Catalina resets the symlink on reboot. sudo chflags schg (path to link) prevents MacOS from touching the link.

Comment: It seems that doing this prevents system writes to the folder for certain functionality — for example, doing this on Desktop/ means screenshots aren't saved to the Desktop when doing CMD+SHIFT+3/4 - doing it via Finder on the symlink itself seems to work

Answer (score 2):

You can try using symlinks. There is a pretty good post for dropbox usage [here](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.imore.com/how-sync-your-documents-desktop-and-any-other-folder-dropbox%3Famp) - try to adopt this for your needs.

These are the essential parts:

Navigate in Terminal to your Dropbox folder by typing

```
cd /Users/YourMacUsernameHere/Dropbox
```

and then hitting return. A new line in Terminal will appear that's

```
Your-Computer-Name:Dropbox YourUserName$
```

Create your symbolic link by typing

```
ln -s ~/FolderNameHere
```

and hitting return. A folder will appear in your Dropbox folder with the alias/shortcut arrow and it will immediately begin uploading.

To create a symlink to your Desktop, type

```
ln -s ~/Desktop
```

Comment: This is almost what I wanted! However this creates only a link to the "original" folder in my "new" folder (where original refers to the folder with all the files and the new folder refers to where the files are meant to appear). How can I create a symlink where automatically all the files from the original folder get a symlink displayed in the new folder?